Hyperoperation notation
Given that
$H_1(x,y)=x+y$
$H_2(x,y)=x*y$
$H_3(x,y)=x^y$
$H_4(x,y)= {^y x}$
I want to represent $(((p^{\frac{p}{1+p}}+\ln(p))^{\frac{p}{1+p}}+\ln(p))^{\frac{p}{1+p}}+\ln(p))$ with the $H$ notation.
Is it $H_4(H_1(H_3(p,\frac{p}{1+p}),\ln(p),3)$ ? Or is there something better?
If this is right, then I further suspect that $H_4(H_1(H_3(p,\frac{p}{1+p}),\ln(p),\infty)$ diverges because of the addend $\ln(p)$ but the exponent $\frac{p}{1+p}$ is less than $1$ so I don't know.
